# QasMixer: Why can't I hear anything on Input Source, 1 and Input Source, 2?

Tags: sound, soundcard, ubuntu-studio

I have a front and rear mic input on my PC. I can only hear mic input when either front or rear mic is connected to Input Source, 0. If I switch either front or mic input to Input Source, 1 or Input Source, 2 I don't hear anything. Also increased front and rear mic boost with no effect. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? TIA.

[Screenshot of QasMixer and Carla config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGFq4.png)

OS Information:

```
(Ubuntu Studio)
ubuntustudio@UBUNTU-STUDIO:~$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Hardware Information:

```
ubuntustudio@UBUNTU-STUDIO:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Z170 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus (rev 31)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V (rev 31)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208B [GeForce GT 730] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK208 HDMI/DP Audio Controller (rev a1)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

```
ubuntustudio@UBUNTU-STUDIO:~$ arecord -L
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
surround21
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
samplerate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Samplerate Library
speexrate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Speex Resampler
jack
    JACK Audio Connection Kit
oss
    Open Sound System
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
upmix
    Plugin for channel upmix (4,6,8)
vdownmix
    Plugin for channel downmix (stereo) with a simple spacialization
sysdefault:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC3861 Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC3861 Analog
    Front speakers
dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC3861 Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=2
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC3861 Alt Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC3861 Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=PCH,DEV=2
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC3861 Alt Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC3861 Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=2
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC3861 Alt Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC3861 Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=2
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC3861 Alt Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
usbstream:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH
    USB Stream Output
sysdefault:CARD=eX
    Default Audio Device
usbstream:CARD=eX
    ESI MIDIMATE eX
    USB Stream Output
usbstream:CARD=NVidia
    HDA NVidia
    USB Stream Output
```